# Why does createNote on Evernote Python API fail with errorcode 5 (DATA_REQUIRED) though data seems to be provided?

Tags: python, evernote

I'm new to the Evernote python 2.x API and I'm working on some examples. I managed to create a note in the sandbox, but I failed in creating a note with attachment. I followed the example code given in https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/creating_notes.php and I end up calling

```
try:
    note = noteStore.createNote(authToken, ourNote)
except Errors.EDAMUserException, edue:
    ## Something was wrong with the note data
    ## See EDAMErrorCode enumeration for error code explanation
    ## http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Errors.html#Enum_EDAMErrorCode
    print "EDAMUserException:", edue
    return None
```

The parameter ourNote was printed as

```
Note(contentHash=None, updated=None, created=None, deleted=None, contentLength=None, title='testtitel2', notebookGuid=None, content='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd"><en-note>testbody<br /><br />Attachment with hash 3430623163666630303562663662393263386539663366613134636630323736: <br /><en-media type="text/plain" hash="3430623163666630303562663662393263386539663366613134636630323736" /><br /></en-note>', tagNames=None, updateSequenceNum=None, tagGuids=None, active=None, attributes=None, guid=None, resources=[Resource(noteGuid=None, height=None, width=None, alternateData=None, mime='text/plain', updateSequenceNum=None, duration=None, attributes=ResourceAttributes(recoType=None, sourceURL=None, cameraMake=None, timestamp=None, altitude=None, clientWillIndex=None, longitude=None, fileName=None, attachment=None, latitude=None, applicationData=None, cameraModel=None), guid=None, data=Data(body='This is the content of testfile, aaa, bbb\\n\n', bodyHash='40b1cff005bf6b92c8e9f3fa14cf0276', size=44), active=None, recognition=None)])
```

I'm getting

EDAMUserException: EDAMUserException(errorCode=5, parameter='[3430623163666630303562663662393263386539663366613134636630323736]')

which says DATA_REQUIRED. What exactly is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, you are missing a resource that is in your ENML. See [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/evernotegists/5313824#file-main-py) to make sure you are handling your file attached to your note properly.

Comment: Actually this is the piece of code I had originally used. To double check I copied your mentioned sample code and still got errorcode 5. So I assume it is an issue of making up the resources parameter of makeNote. But from the content of parameter ourNote in the call of createNote (see my original post) I still don't see a mandatory member missing.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by changing line 20 in the [sample code](https://gist.github.com/evernotegists/5313824#file-main-py) from

```
hexhash = binascii.hexlify(resource.data.bodyHash)
```

to

```
hexhash = resource.data.bodyHash
```

which makes it work. I don't know what the hexlify() was intended for here. I will ask the Evernote guys. The parameter in the error message in my original post was the "hexlified" hash. Btw: in order to determine the bodyHash I'm using the way described [here](http://virantha.com/2013/11/04/creating-new-notes-and-attaching-files-using-evernotes-python-api/).